# Application crashes after using react-native-chart-android

Tags: react-native

I am making an app using react native version 0.29. I need an chart library for my android app. After embedding react-native-chart-android in my app I got the following error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer for the problem. This library is written for below RN v 0.25. So they are using 
      import React,{ requireNativeComponent, Component, PropTypes, View } from     'react-native';
in their import statements. For RN updated version they should have import React and Component from react. 
For that I will raise a PR in Github.